# How can I run scheduled recursion with scala/akka?

Tags: scala, recursion, out-of-memory, akka

How can I run something like this without take java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread?

```
def doSomething(): Unit = {
    akka.actor
        .ActorSystem(System)
        .scheduler
        .scheduleOnce(1 seconds)(doSomething()) 
}
```

Comment: What is the "something like this" that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you call `doSomething` a lot.

Akka's `ActorSystem` is a relatively resource-intensive object. It's generally meant to be around for the lifetime of your program. Under the hood, an `ActorSystem` manages a handful of `Thread`s in a `ThreadPool`, which all of the actors run on. That `ThreadPool` stays alive until you tell it to shut down.

If you call `doSomething` often, you're creating a new `ActorSystem` and therefore a new 8 or so threads each time. Eventually the JVM won't be able to make any more threads, which will lead to your OOM error.

The solution is to make your `ActorSystem` instance available "globally", and make sure to shut it down when your program is finished.

```
object MyGlobals {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
}

def doSomething() = {
  MyGlobals.actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(...)
}

// and then at the end of your program
actorSystem.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the scheduleOnce method use the schedule method and pass the arguments accordingly. To see an example visit the link present below.
For more information visit here : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to execute a function every 1 second, you could something like this:

```
def doSomething(): Unit = ???

akka.actor.ActorSystem()
  .scheduler
  .schedule(initialDelay = 0 seconds, interval = 1 second)(doSomething())
```